# Progressively disappearing text based on Viewport width... with ellipses..!

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two-list-item unordered list absolutely positioned to the top right of the viewport.

```
<header id="top-bar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">David Bowie</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="../includes/sign_out.php" class="signUp"     name="signUp">Sign Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
#top-bar {
    height:47px;
    background-color:rgb(43, 165, 43);
    border-bottom:3px solid rgb(22, 83, 22);
    font-size:0.75em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#top-bar ul {
    margin:0; padding:0 0.25em;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
#top-bar ul > li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    line-height:47px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#top-bar ul > li:first-child{
    margin-left:0.45em;
    background:orange; /* testing purposes */
}
```

The last child `li`'s content never changes. However, *the first child `li`'s content is variable*.

At full viewport width, the variable content is of little consequence. But as the viewport decreases, especially at mobile viewports, the text should begin to recede BEHIND the containing `div` and a series of (...) should substitute for the receding hidden text. At a certain width, the size of the containing `li` will become fixed and the receding will stop.

I'm not quite sure how to execute this. Can this be done purely with CSS? I feel like Javascript would have to play a role in substituting out content for the ellipses.

Unfortunately I don't have a whole lot of programming experience under my belt, especially with regards to Javascript, and I'm in a bit of a hurry to develop this.

If any of you more natural programmers out there know how to deal with this I'd love to hear ya.

Thanks.

Comment: CSS?? Any fiddle to explain your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ellipsis for truncated text using CSS3 [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

```
<style>
ul{
    background: #aaa;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
li{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Was unaware of the `text-overflow` property